# How to fix zsh: correct 'deploy' to '_deploy' [nyae]?

Tags: rake, zsh

I am playing around with Octopress/github pages. When I type rake deploy, the terminal always outputs zsh: correct 'deploy' to '_deploy' [nyae]?. I enter n.

What do I need to do in order not to display 'zsh: correct 'deploy' to '_deploy' [nyae]? ' in my terminal?

Thanks in advance.

```
rake deploy 
zsh: correct 'deploy' to '_deploy' [nyae]?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quick fix: disable autocorrect. In your `~/.zshrc`:

```
unsetopt correct_all
```

If you want autocorrect but not for `rake`:

```
alias rake='nocorrect rake'
```

Answer (score 0):

I beleive the `unsetopt correct_all` doesnt work any more with the latest update.
A more robust solution would be to add in your `~/.zshrc` file

```
DISABLE_CORRECTION="true"
```